# How to return new object of Generic Type with parameter driver in Page Object Model

Tags: java, selenium, generics, reflection, pageobjects

I use Selenium.
I have Page Object like this:

```
    public class Portal extends Utils{

    private WebDriver driver;
    private final By getReason= By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Get Sol')]");

    public Portal(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public VisitReason clickCurrentReason() {
        clickIn(getReason);
        return new VisitReason(driver);
    }
}
```

I would like this method: clickCurrentReason() return new Object extend Utils class and passed it parameter: driver.
How to do it?
I know I have to use generics. I found part of solution:

```
public<T extends Utils> T clickCurrentReason(){
        clickIn(getReason);
        return (T)(driver);        
    }
```

But how passed in return: "return new Object(driver)"

@Test method:

```
public void Test() {
        TestingEnv testingEnv = new TestingEnv(driver);

        Portal portal = testingEnv.openPage();

        VisitReason visitReason = portal.clickCurrentReason();

        //sometimes instead of the last line it will be: VisitInSpot visitInSpot = portal.clickCurrentReason();
        //sometimes instead of the last line it will be: VisitBack visitBack = portal.clickCurrentReason();

    }
```

Comment: So basically you need to `return new T(driver)`?

Comment: Can you add an example of this method being called? That might help answer the question, but I suspect you are looking for [class reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html).

Comment: Greg Burghardt exactly

Comment: example method is called: public void Test() {
  TestingEnv testingEnv = new TestingEnv(driver);
  
  Portal portal = testingEnv.openPage();
  
  VisitReason visitReason = portal.clickCurrentReason();
  
  //sometimes it will be: VisitInSpot visitInSpot = portal.clickCurrentReason();
 }

Comment: Please add that to your question. It is too difficult to read in a comment.